# Can some advise me on how to solve this system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have the following system of 3 equations and 3 unknowns:
$$c_{0} = \frac{x_0}{x_0 + x_1},\ \ c_{1} = \frac{x_1}{x_1 + x_2},\ \ \ c_{2} = \frac{x_2}{x_2 + x_0},$$
where all $c_i\!\in\!(0,1)$ are known and all $x_i > 0$ are unknown. Am I right in that the solution of this system is the nullspace of the following matrix? $$\mathbf{A}=\left[\begin{matrix}(c_0-1)& c_0 & 0 \\ 0 & (c_1-1) & c_1 \\ c_2 & 0 & (c_2-1) \end{matrix}\right].$$
If so, I want to find the non-trivial solution, i.e. the basis for $null(\mathbf{A})$.

p.s. I have attempted to simplify $\mathbf{A}$ to its reduced row echelon form $rref(\mathbf{A})$. I know that $null(\mathbf{A}) = null(rref(\mathbf{A}))$, but I get a diagonal matrix for $rref(\mathbf{A})$. So does this mean that $null(\mathbf{A}) = \mathbf{0}$, and therefore, there are no solutions to the system?

Comment: That is basically right, but you also need to consider that $x_0+x_1,x_1+x_2,x_2+x_0\neq 0.$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have never dealt with a solution to a problem that warrants me computing the nullspace of a matrix. So this a bit foreign to me. I just needed verification is all.

Comment: @KentaS Yes, my specific problem guarantees that the denominators are all non-zero.

Comment: I can help you in computing the nullspace, if you want. But perhaps your problem is how to obtain this matrix? What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes please, thanks!

Comment: you can consider the system to be homogeneous, instead of thinking to nullspace; do you know when a homogeneous is solvable ?

Comment: @GCab No I do not, can you elaborate?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know how to obtain the matrix, because it follows straightforwardly from the system of equations. Could you help me express the general form of the nullspace symbolically? i.e. in terms of $c_i$.

Comment: So I do recommend that you study the general theory about the solution of a $n \times m$ system of linear equations,  homogeneous \inhomogeneous, which involves analyzing the rank of the coefficients matrix and of the complete (coeff. + known terms) one. It is not the case to expose it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We rewrite the equations as a system of linear equations $Ax=0$ with
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} c_0-1 & c_0 & 0 \\ 0 & c_1-1 & c_1 \\
c_2 & 0 & c_2-1& \end{pmatrix}
$$
and $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2)^t$.
The nullspace of $A$ is non-trivial if and only if $\det(A)=0$.
We have
$$
\det(A)=2c_0c_1c_2 - c_0c_1 - c_0c_2 + c_0 - c_1c_2 + c_1 + c_2 - 1.
$$
The trivial solution $x=0$, i.e., $x_0=x_1=x_2=0$ is forbidden by you.

So let us suppose that $\det(A)=0$ and $2c_0c_1 - c_0 - c_1 + 1\neq 0$. Then we can express $c_2$ by $c_0$ and $c_1$ and then $\ker(A)$ is spanned by

$$
\begin{pmatrix} c_1-1\\ -c_0 \\- 2c_0c_1 + c_0 + c_1 - 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: Thanks for this. I see that your matrix is the transpose of mine. Is there any particular reason for this? Does the transpose of a matrix have the same nullspace? Also, could you perhaps help me derive a basis for the nullspace as well?

Comment: I have the same matrix as you, sorry. For $\det(A)\neq 0$ there is only the zero solution. For you the the empty solution with no basis. Otherwise we have solutions, which I will edit.

Comment: Ok I see. I have also just added that all $x_i > 0$.

Comment: I am slightly confused as to how you computed the Kernel, but at a glance, multiplying it by $A$ does not yield the zero-vector.

Comment: It does yield zero, if you use that $2c_0c_1c_2\pm \cdots =0$ because of $\det(A)=0$ then. A good test for you is to take $(c_0,c_1,c_2)=(1,1,0)$, because then you are in this case ( I know that you have $c_i$ restricted to $(0,1)$, but just for the computation of the kernel that you see the nullspace is this).

Comment: Okay I see now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ is a solution, so is $\lambda(x_0,x_1,x_2)$. So we may choose $x_0$ arbitrarily and draw

$$x_1=\frac{1-c_0}{c_0}x_0,\\x_2=\frac{c_2}{1-c_2}x_0.$$