# Can anyone advise me on how to solve this minimisation problem?

Tags: optimization, regression, least-squares, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I have the following system of 3 equations and 3 unknowns:
$$c_{0} = \frac{x_0}{x_0 + x_1},\ \ c_{1} = \frac{x_1}{x_1 + x_2},\ \ \ c_{2} = \frac{x_2}{x_2 + x_0},$$
where $c_i\!\in\!(0,1)$ are known and $x_i > 0$ are unknown. This is described by the system $\textbf{A}\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$, where

$$\mathbf{A}=\left[\begin{matrix}(c_0-1)& c_0 & 0 \\ 0 & (c_1-1) & c_1 \\ c_2 & 0 & (c_2-1) \end{matrix}\right]\ \ \text{ and }\ \ \textbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix}\right]$$

I initially posted here: [Can some advise me on how to solve this system of equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588068/can-some-advise-me-on-how-to-solve-this-system-of-equations/3588094?noredirect=1#comment7379358_3588094) , hoping to get some advice on finding a basis for the nullspace of $\textbf{A}$. But it turns out that in the general case, only the trivial solution, $\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$, holds. This means that, for the given conditions for $c_i$ and $x_i$ above, there is no exact solution. Therefore, I want to reformulate my problem to the following: *Given the system $\textbf{A}\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}$, compute $\textbf{x}$ such that $|\!|\textbf{b}|\!|$ is minimised.*

Can anyone give me advice on how to solve the above minimisation problem?

p.s. It was pointed out to me by @brenderson that the above reformulation is meaningless. Therefore, my question now is: how do I reformulate the "exact" system above in such a way that I can get the "best possible" numerical solution for $\textbf{x}$? I am no longer sure how to formulate this mathematically.

Comment: You're trying to minimize $\|Ax\|$ over $x>0$? Taking $x\to 0$ gives $\inf_{x > 0}\|Ax\| = 0$. I'm confused by what is the optimization problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @brenderson Okay, I see that I haven't formulated the problem correctly. Given your understanding of my problem, how would reformulate my problem to get the "best possible" numerical solution for $\textbf{x}$? That is essentially what I want to solve.

Comment: It depends on your specific values of $c_0,c_1,c_2$. If $A$ is nonsingular, then there is only one solution to your problem, namely $x=0$. If $A$ is singular, then there are infinitely many solutions to your problem (and $x=0$ is still one of them).

Comment: Generally for $Ax=b$ with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $m\le n$, there is either a unique solution ($m=n=\text{rank}(A)$) or infinitely many solutions ($\text{rank}(A)<n$). If there are infinite solutions, a simple way to find the "best possible solution" is to look for the solution with minimum norm that still solves the equations. That is, we seek to solve $\inf\{ \|x\| : Ax = b \}$. This is a convex problem that can be solved using a variety of computing tools, such as CVX. If $\text{rank}(A)=m<n$, the solution is $x^* = A^\top(AA^\top)^{-1}b$. However, in your case $b=0$ so $x^*=0$.

Comment: @brenderson Ok, I see. Thanks a lot for this insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want - but here is one approach : You can try to minimize $A \mathbf{x}$ for $\mathbf{x}$ of a fixed norm. When $A$ has a nontrivial kernel, this will give you $\mathbf{x}$ of the given norm living inside the null-space. If $A$ is nonsingular, then actually you are solving:

$$\mathbf{x} \quad \text{ that minimizes } \quad \frac{\|A \mathbf{x}\|}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}$$

Note however that such an $\mathbf{x}$ also has the property that:

$$\mathbf{y} = A\mathbf{x} \quad \text{ maximises } \quad \frac{\|A^{-1} \mathbf{y} \|}{\|\mathbf{y}\|}$$

This sort of problem is pretty much determining [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) of $A^{-1}$:

$$\| A^{-1} \|  = \text{sup}\{\|A^{-1} y \| : y \in K^n \text{ with } \|y\|=1\}$$

and for different norms there are different results. In the case of the $L^2$ norm (euclidean-distance), the operator norm $\|A^{-1}\|_2$ coincides with the spectral norm (see proof [here for example](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/algebra/node12.html)) - and the value of $\mathbf{y}$ you want lives in the eigenspace of the largest eigenvalue of $(A^{-1})^T A^{-1}$, which is something you can compute for your explicit example.

Comment: Thanks for your insight into the problem :)